# Brakes slide when pressing on them

Tags: brakes, hyundai, sonata

I own a 2001 Hyundai Sonata, and when I go press on my brakes, the car will slow down, but when I press down on them hard (for an immediate stop) they slide for some reason.

Is this common? I've put new pads on them, but the issue still persists.

There's brake fluid in the reservoir.

Comment: What do you mean by 'they slide'? Does the car still slow down? Do the tyres slide on the road?

Comment: No, the tires don't even slide. The car slows down, and slides before stopping. Usually when you press on brakes, the car stops and the tire slides and you normally hear that tire sounds on immediate stopping.

Comment: Are the wheels locking up?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an ABS failure.

Comment: There are also variants w/o ABS for that car.

Comment: There are very very few cars built without ABS since around 1995, if any. ABS is only operational on vehicles above a road speed of around 5mph. If they were to work below app. 5mph you would be unable to bring the vehicle to a stop with the footbrake.

Comment: During the late '90's, most of the Japanese and Korean cars did not have ABS. They were an option, but well over 90% of them shipped without. I mean, it's standard today, but at the turn of the century the Japanese and Koreans just didn't have it right. We tried to special order a 98 Mazda Protege ES with ABS ... it still came without.